# Where are the modifier scripts in the Blender package contents folder?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I need to find where Blender has applied their modifiers and physics scripts within their program so that I can install and place my own that I have. Either it has been a very long day already or I am simply blind because I have looked through every file and every option available for several hours now and am about to go crazy. If someone has a file path or can send a screenshot of where it is it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Blender's modifiers and physics related routines are written in C/C++, you won't find them in the scripts directory. Download Blender's source [here](https://www.blender.org/download/#source) as an archive or use [GIT](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Tools/Git)