# Is there a way to change the default Booean operation type?

Tags: modifiers

I use the Boolean modifier a lot and almost always use the "Difference" option. It would be great if I could make that the default rather than "Intersection". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked before in 2015: [Where are the modifier scripts in the Blender package contents folder?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33031/where-are-the-modifier-scripts-in-the-blender-package-contents-folder)
They are part of the main app coding, so unless things have changed, not easily modified.
I would like to do this, too, as I use Booleans a lot for 3D print drawing.
Not changing dimensions from millimetres to CM would be good as well.